# Custom Charts in PAIR-code / Facets (Visualization of Dataset in Python)

Tags: python, data-visualization, visualization, facet

I am using [PAIR-code/Facets](https://github.com/PAIR-code/facets) to visualize some aspects of my dataset. However, I would like to do some tweaks and add some custom charts and columns to "facets overview". A Demo can be found [here.](https://pair-code.github.io/facets/)

In their documentation I found:
*"additionally, the feature statistics proto allows for custom charts to be stored for any feature. If the input proto to the visualization contains any custom charts, they will be listed in the dropdown as well."*
Also I went through the code and tried to figure out how to implement a custom graph (i.e. a matplotlib graph), but until now I am very unsuccesful.

Is there anyone with a similar problem or even better a solution who could give me hint?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What tweaks would you like to do?

Comment: I would like to insert a radar chart (or any other matplotlib plot) instead of the given histogram.